# About rooted android device and custom ROM

Tags: android

I have Rooted android device LG E400. I want my app to launch as home application immediately after device is booted. I want that device can run only my single app and disable all other functionality.
Also as my app is performing all things automatically, i want to disable the Buttons (Home, Back and Menu etc) so no one can access it manually. How to achieve this? I need a help on this.

I want to take complete control on device. How to do this. Is rooting is enough or do i need to cutomize the ROM? Please guide me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a custom ROM for this. If you have no experience building custom rom's then these videos might be of help:

Android Internals : 

[Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0)

[Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFqELLB1Kk8)

Comment: Thanks, i also want to know that. If i want to make my device run only single app at start and also that app want to communicate remotely with website then what should i do in this case?